# Maya Python: How to convert a list to an Integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, python-2.x, maya

I am still learning python, so bear with me.
I get the last keyframe of an animation between keyframe 1000 and 2000.

```
shotLength = cmds.keyframe(time=(1000,2000) ,query=True)
del shotLength[:-1]
print shotLength
```

Result:

```
[1090.0]
```

At this point only the desired keyframe remains in the list as a value.
I convert this value to an integer like so:

```
shotLengthInt = list(map(int, shotLength))
print shotLengthInt
```

Result:

```
[1090]
```

Now i want to add +1 to this value so it would look like this:

```
[1091]
```

I just cant figure out how.

Comment: `shotLengthInt[0] += 1`

Comment: are you sure you actually want to have your `int` in a list? if not, you can simply do, at the beginning: `lastFrame = int(shotLength[-1]) + 1`; otherwise you can go with `shotLengthInt[0] += 1` (as @AK47 suggested), it just feels overcomplicated...

Comment: @mapofemergence Thank you! That is actually perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the following:

```
shotLengthInt = list(map(int, shotLength))
print shotLengthInt
```

We can pass a lambda function to map, to achieve it:

```
shotLengthInt = map(lambda x: int(x) + 1, shotLength)
print shotLengthInt
```

Comment: You can just use `shotLengthInt = map(lambda x: int(x) + 1, shotLength)`

Comment: Yes your right, its unnecessary to convert to list again, thank you, I'll edit the ans.

Answer (score 1):

Your value is contained within a list (notice the square brackets), so to update this value by 1, you need to reference the first index of the list and increment that by 1

```
>>> shotLengthInt = [1090]
>>> shotLengthInt
> [1090]
>>> shotLengthInt[0] += 1
>>> shotLengthInt
> [1091]
```

You can also remove the `list()` when assigning the value to `shotLengthInt`

```
>>> shotLength = [1090.0]
>>> shotLength
> [1090.0]
>>> shotLengthInt = map(int, shotLength)
>>> shotLengthInt
> [1090]
```